# JRE error when trying to install Matlab Compiler Runtime

Tags: java, matlab, ubuntu

Once again, I spent much time trying to get something to work without success.
I want to install MATLAB Compiler Runtime on my Ubuntu 13.04, where there is no MATLAB installed.
Here's what I did:
I downloaded the 64-bit Linux version R2012b(8.0) off of

`http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/index.html?s_cid=BB`.

Then, I switched into the folder and tried to install via

`sudo ./install` just to receive the following message:

`Error: Cannot locate Java Runtime Environment (JRE).
The directory /home/konni/Downloads/MCR_R2012b_glnxa64_installer/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre does not exist.`

And, it does not exist indeed, but there exists a folder with "glnxa86" instead of "glnx86". I wouldn't just want to rename it, though.

I do have a JRE installed on my machine, btw:

`java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)`

I have absolutely no clue what to do. The problems I found using google didn't quite help me, either...

Maybe you have an idea?
I'd greatly appreciate any help! :-)

Comment: Matlab expects the oracle JVM, if this is already installed no other copy should be installed and the bug in the installation script is skipped. Instructions for java installation: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Java/Installation/Oracle_Java?redirect=no

Comment: I think I messed something up when trying to install the Oracle Java. Now, when I type "java -version" it tells me "bash: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute file". I think I did is as said on the website you gave me, though. Any idea what could have gone wrong? It's somehow a wrong symlink, huh?

Comment: Still works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If the only problem is finding the JRE, then the command line switch -javadir will get you done:

./install -javadir /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently when installing a software that required a 7.13 MCR on an Ubuntu 17.10.

In this

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/matlab-7-5-compiled-runtime-for-64-bit-linux-installation-no-jre-error-838281/

I found that the 32 bit version installs fine, and it did, but obviously, that didn't solve my problem.

However, I found a way to do it. The trick is that the installer needs the old JRE (1.5) and will not work with JDK 8.

So the first step is to run

```
./MCRInstaller.bin -is:extract
```

this will create a directory called istemp... something, for me istemp23732345211606.

> ls

`jre1.5.0-linux-amd64.bin  JVMNotFound.txt  setup.jar  Verify.jar`

It is tempting to run the setup.jar directly, do try, but with Java 8, I only got the following error message:

> Could not load wizard specified in /wizard.inf (104)

But perhaps it will work for you. People who get the above mentioned error with wizard.inf should look further, because the installer needs JDK 5 to run.

I chose not to use the bundled version but downloaded the JDK 5 from Oracle. The bundled version might work as well - I did not try.

You can download JDK 5 from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jdk-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR

Extract the downloaded archive (chmod +x the bin and run), then copy the files to /usr/lib/jvm/java5

Rename the jdk1.5.0_022 or anything to jdk1.5.0 to make it simple.

Fix attributes:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/javac" 1
```

Now chose the jdk 5 as default

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And selecting the appropriate option.

Check that it worked

```
java -version
```

You should see something like this:

> java version "1.5.0_22" Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard
>   Edition (build 1.5.0_22-b03) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   1.5.0_22-b03, mixed mode)

Now you can run the setup.jar file in the extracted directory (istemp...)

```
sudo java -jar setup.jar
```

I recommend that you chose a contemporary java by running

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

again.

Answer (score 1):

When running the installer.sh, use the command line option "-is:javahome [path to your java jre folder]".
For instance, I installed below a java 8 jre on an old matlab compiler 2007b as follow:

> sudo /opt/installer.sh -console -is:javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. The problem is you are installing 64-bit matlab on 32-bit ubuntu. use 32-bit matlab and install in ubuntu 32-bit. use 64-bit matlab and install in ubuntu 64-bit. Please like the answer if it was helpful.