# Matlab Compiler Runtime installation file cannot locate Java Runtime Environment

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-compiler

A collaborator has sent me some Matlab code which requires an old MCR version (7.14). I have an installation binary from them, but when I run it I am immediately faced with the message

```
No Java Runtime Environment(JRE) was found on this system
```

Has anyone experienced this before? I cannot get around the problem. I have JRE installed. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How did you install the JRE?

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515707

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I installed JRE using the following:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Comment: @StephenC this isn't a duplicate of that issue as best as I can tell, I am forced to use a bundled installer  binary which actually has JRE built into it (I have used it successfully on numerous other ubuntu machines).

Comment: Did you update the path? Specifying MATLAB_JAVA variable to point to the jre folder in the system environment path could help.

Comment: If the installer has a built in JRE it should not matter if you have installed Java otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause may be that `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is not set, or that it is set incorrectly.   The variable should point to the installation directory for the JRE / JDK whose `java` command you are running.

(Note: a correct `JAVA_HOME` is never a `bin` directory, so if you have set your `$JAVA_HOME` to a `bin` directory you have done it wrong!)

Thus, the solution may simply be to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable (correctly) in your shell before running the `MCR` installer.

> I have used it [the MCR installer] successfully on numerous other Ubuntu machines.

This is suggestive to me that your problem is an incorrect `JAVA_HOME` ...

---

Another possible solution would be to follow the instructions in the `MATLAB` documentation for doing a "non-interactive" install of `MCR`.

---

There is apparently a `README` file in the zip file.  It may contain information about command line options for the installer that relate to the version you are using.

---

Finally, I suspect that the `install` command is actually a shell script.  There may be clues in the script about command line options and other alternatives for installing.